# Python pydantic model get field as string

Tags: python, model

From the code below, is there a way I can get name as string, not the value, but the field name itself?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name = 'Jane Doe'

user = User(id='123', name='John')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of fields via the [`__fields__`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#model-properties) attribute:

```py
User.__fields__
# or
user.__fields__
# {
#     'id': ModelField(name='id', type=int, required=True),
#     'name': ModelField(name='name', type=str, required=False, default='Jane Doe')
# }
```

and consequently, a list of the field names via:

```py
list(User.__fields__.keys()))
# or
list(user.__fields__.keys()))
# ['id', 'name']
```

Answer (score 1):

just for fun)

```
class Job(BaseModel):
    name: str

try: Job.name
except Exception as e: 
    field_name = str(e)
```